# Preventing other user view post using policy Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('{username}/posts','PostController@editorPost')->name('post.editor');
```

I want to prevent other editors from viewing the post that doesn't belong to them. I tried to make PostPolicy like this:

```
public function view(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id || $user->hasRole('admin');
}
```

How can I authorize user in my PostController? and did I write the policy correctly, since it uses username not user id? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I authorize user in my PostController?

You have options when it comes to authorization. You can call `authorize` on the Controller, call the Gate, `authorize` method on a FormRequest or use `can` on a User model.

```
public function show(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    // controller authorization helper
    $this->authorize('view', $post);
    // user authorization helper
    if ($request->user()->cant('view', $post)) {
        // return redirect / throw exception
    }
}
```

> and did I write the policy correctly, since it uses username not user id?

By the time this policy method is ran the current User is already authenticated and known and the Post is what you are passing into the authorization method. How ever you need to resolve the Post or other entity a policy is for is done before the authorization call.

If you want an 'admin' to be able to pass all authorization checks for a policy you can define a `before` method to allow this:

```
public function before($user, $ability)
{
    if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Thanks.

You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps that you would follow to achieve what you want.

1) Usually, I would let artisan create and register the policy object for me by running following command

```
php artisan make:policy -m=Model
```

However, if you want to manually register the policy then, you need to map them in your AuthServiceProvider. e.g.

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Post' => 'App\Policies\PostPolicy',
];
```

2) You already have logic in place in the model policy .

3) In the editPost action of your controller right before anything, you would can authorize the person to view the post. something like

```
$this->authorize('view', $post);
```

4) You also have access to @can and @endcan block in blade.

As far as your username or user id question goes, you have access to whole user object so you can take any attribute off user to run the check.

Hope that helps.

Here is the actual code from Laravel codebase

```
/**
 * Determine if the given ability should be granted for the current user.
 *
 * @param  string  $ability
 * @param  array|mixed  $arguments
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
 */
public function authorize($ability, $arguments = [])
{
    $result = $this->raw($ability, $arguments);

    if ($result instanceof Response) {
        return $result;
    }

    return $result ? $this->allow() : $this->deny();
}
```

Here are relevant links

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies

Comment: $this->authorize('view', $post); like u wrote, it doesn't need user variable? since i need to filter is it the post belongs to this user.

Comment: Once you map your User Model to Policy Model, you already get User in the policy and for the post you just pass the post into it.

public function view(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id || $user->hasRole('admin');
}